# Display title from tableview cell in different viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I can't seem to figure this very simple thing out. I got a UIViewController with 2 buttons, each button links to a different UITableViewController, when I click on a cell in the UITableViewController I want the input of the cell to display in the pressed button. The input comes from an array.

Some of my code:

**MainView.m:**

```
- (void)tableViewController:(TableViewController1 *)tableViewController didSelectRow (NSInteger)rowIndex 
{
NSLog(@"Selected row number: %d",rowIndex);   
}
```

**TableView1.m:**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

[self.delegate tableViewController:self didSelectRow:indexPath.row];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I got the title of the buttons defined with a method like this:

**MainView.m**:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[self.industry setTitle:self.industryText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.education setTitle:self.educationText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Industry & Education are the buttons itself. IndustryText & EducationText are the placeholders for the name.

Comment: So in the delegate callback you just want to setTitle again?

Comment: You can use delegate and a protocol with just a single method.

Comment: @Wain I want to set the button title in my mainviewcontroller to the cell that was clicked in a tableviewcontroller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your MainView which has the 2 buttons add the following code:

**MainViewController.h**

```
- (void)selectedFirstButtonText:(NSString *)strText;
```

**MainViewController.m**

On the first button touch event add the following code:

```
- (IBAction)btnFirstTouch:(id)sender {
    FirstTableViewController *firstVC = [[FirstTableViewController alloc] init];
    firstVC.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:firstVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Now implement the **delegate method:**

```
- (void)selectedFirstButtonText:(NSString *)strText {
    [self.btnFirst setTitle:strText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

**FirstTableViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MainViewController.h"

@class MainViewController;

@interface FirstTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDataSource> 
@property(nonatomic, assign) MainViewController *delegate;


@end
```

Now in your **FirstTableViewController.m**

```
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(selectedFirstButtonText:)]) {
        [self.delegate selectedFirstButtonText:cell.textLabel.text];
        NSLog(@"Selected Text");
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```

[Sample Project Dropbox Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m5mxjv6rilaboep/ST-16656665.zip)

Comment: @Tarayaa Did you check the sample project its working as per your need

Comment: Wow yeah this project does exactly what I need.

Comment: Im gonna check the code tommorow cause im offline now, thanks!

Comment: @Tarayaa If it solved your issue please mark the answer as checked. So that the question will be removed from unanswered section.

Comment: Worked! Thanks a lot, helped me understand the entire proces.

Answer (score 0):

This will set the button title to the text of the cell:

Change the delegate callback to MainView.

MainView.m:

```
- (void)tableViewController:(TableViewController1 *)tableViewController didSelectText (NSString *)text 
{
    NSLog(@"Selected text: %@", text); 
    [self.industry setTitle:text forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
}
```

And change the data that TableView1 sends to its delegate.

TableView1.m:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *text = [[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] textLabel] text];
    [self.delegate tableViewController:self didSelectText:text];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

For this to work (compile without warnings) you want to update the delegate protocol which defines:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and change it to:

```
- (void)tableViewController:(TableViewController1 *)tableViewController didSelectText (NSString *)text
```

Comment: This is giving me all kinds of errors, not sure how to implement it i guess

Comment: Added a few details about what to put where. You do need to change a few places as the delegate method you're currently using is passing information that you can't use so you need to amend it.

Comment: Fixed the errors but its not displaying any update in the buttons.. :(

Comment: Change the log statement to NSLog(@"Selected text: %@ (%@)", text, self.industry); and tell me what it prints out.

Comment: Is self.delegate actually set to the main view ?

Comment: I have no clue, im kinda new to this.

Comment: Ok, so you need to fix that. Something similar to Nanz answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pass in a reference of the parent class to the 2 UITableViewControllers. So your TableView1.h file will have a property of type MainView.

**TableView1.h**

```
@interface TableView1 : UITableViewController {
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) MainView *parent;
```

Then when you instantiate your TableView1 class, pass a reference

**MainView.m**

```
TableView1 *tableView = [[UITableViewController alloc]init];
tableView.parent = self;
```

Finally in your delegate method set the text of the button using your parent reference

**TableView1.m**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath {

[self.delegate tableViewController:self didSelectRow:indexPath.row];
[self.parent.education setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```